# JQuery Datepicker - different hover behaviors for specific cells / date types?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

is it possible to assign different hover methods for the different date types?

For example:

```
beforeShowDay: function(dDate){
              if(condition1){
                  //assign specific method to the "available" type / cell
                  return [true, 'Available', 'specific text'];
              }else if(condition2){
                  //assign specific method to the "not available" type / cell
                  return [false, 'Full', 'specific text'];
              }
              //and so on...
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to access the particular cell elements of the datepicker table. I know how to give each cell the same hover function, but dont know how to assign different functions for the specific date types.

Changing color and stuff with CSS would work, but I need some additional functions within the hover funcs. e.g. displaying some text in another div.

---

#### Solved

I found a solution for my Problem, but it goes in a pretty different direction as supposed.
With the following code I was able to define different hover functions for each of my cell-types / date-types:

```
function setCellHover() {
$(".ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td").mouseenter(function() {

    if($(this).attr("class").indexOf("Available") != -1){
        //do your specific stuff for the "available" cell-type here
    }else if($(this).attr("class").indexOf("Full") != -1){
        //do your specific stuff for the "full" cell-type here
    }//and so on...
    });
}
```

As you can see I just look for the css className of the current cell which is set in the "beforeShowDay" option of the datepicker. Then I assign the different hover behaviours there.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways I know, and neither are very good.

```
var dateElements = $("td[data-month][data-year]", calendar);
dateElements.each(function() {
    var day = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
    var month = $(this).data("month");
    var year = $(this).data("year");
    var dateElement = $(this);
    dateElement.mouseover(function() {
        console.log(day, month, year);
    });
});
```

The other is to generate classes using the odd beforeShowDay optional argument. http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

> beforeShowDayType: Function( Date date )
>   Default: null
>
> A function takes a date as a parameter and must return
>   an array with [0] equal to true/false indicating whether or not this
>   date is selectable, [1] equal to a CSS class name or "" for the
>   default presentation, and [2] an optional popup tooltip for this date.
>   It is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

Your request is a common use case scenario so hopefully someone can provide us with a better method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think you misunderstood my request. As far is I understand you are giving each dateElement the same mouseover function in the first example. But I want to access the particular cells, so I can assign different mouseover functions to the specific dateElements. Or am I wrong? Is there a way e.g. to get the specific dateElement by $("td[data-day][data-month][data-year]" ? I will give it a try.

Comment: Ah I see. I was assuming you wanted to know the date so you could do something different depending on the date. Using my code, you'd write your switch/if/whatnots inside of the mouseover function, and branch depending on the day/month/year variables. If you only have available/full, using beforeShowDayType like you are is indeed the better solution :)